# how I set image in front even on charts and colored sections in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I've insert image in crystal report by following step, In the Section Expert for the section containing the image, check Underlay Following Sections. but, in the report I have charts and colored sections, the image is still in back. Is there a solution for putting the image in front even on charts and colored sections. Thanks for help

Comment: How have you inserted the image? There are several different types of objects that will display the same but have different properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-Click on your image and scroll to the Move option. There you should get either "Move to Front" or "Move to Back". If you get the "Move to Front" option, click on it. That will put the image to the front. If you get the "Move to Back" option then you will have to check your other objects and make sure they are in the back. Right-Click on the object and under "Move" click on "Move to Back". If I remember correctly, charts cannot be moved.

[image]

Comment: there is no option "Move to Front" or "Move to Back" in the image in crystal report, this option is available only for texts box

Comment: Please see screenshot in my answer

Comment: yes i see, but i don't have this option in my crystal report i use Crystal report 2008. what's the number version do you have? thanks

Comment: CR 2008 Version 12.0.0.683